# Why am I not able to use controllerAs syntax in routeProvider when coding for a chrome app?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

angular version: 1.4.9

Hello,

I am packaging an angular web app written in John Papa code style. However I have been facing problems with basic things. One of these things is setting up routeProvider. I would like to configure it in the controller file, but seems to not work. When I configure it directly in the module config it does not accept controllerAs as syntax...

On mycontroller.js file

```
// Has no effect
angular.module('myDearModule').
controller('MyController', MyControllerFn).
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/page', {
       templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
       controller: 'MyController',
       controllerAs: 'mycontrollerVm'
    });
});

function MyControllerFn() {
....
```

Now, if I try it after loading everything, in a kind of module.routing.js file

```
// After setting up module and controller
angular.module('myDearModule').
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/page', {
       templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
       controller: 'MyController',
       controllerAs: 'mycontrollerVm'
    });
});
```

No effect... I also get this error: *[ng:areq] Argument 'MyController' is not a function. Got undefined*

I have tried to switch between views with this recommendation: [Using angular $routeProvider with packaged apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797307/using-angular-routeprovider-with-packaged-apps)

The directive and routing works fine but with no controller setted up :(

The same error happens when I use the ngController  syntax inside the view.

I need to use routing to keep this web working. Am I doing something wrong or just there is no way? Could someone show me an example with controllerAs within a chrome app ? I have found only simple examples (no routing or page changing at all).

Comment: `'MyController' is not a function. Got undefined` Could mean that you have a syntax error  in your controller.

Comment: @AlexSzabó Thank you! I am going to inspect it!

Comment: @AlexSzabó there was a non trivial error in my script file. If you answer the question I will be able to accept your comment as an answer

Comment: glad if I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'MyController' is not a function. Got undefined`

Could mean that you have a syntax error in your controller. There should be no error messages loading controllers, filters, etc. If you find any errors, and correct it, `controllerAs` should work as expected.